# Bitbucket pipeline and angular 11 build error

Tags: angular, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

In my Local dev , when i build project (npm run build:prod)  i have no error .
I use path alias:
this is my tsconfig.app.json

```
 {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@interfaces": ["src/app/interfaces/index.ts"],
      "@services":["src/app/services/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/environment"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/app/interfaces/*"],
      "@interfaces": ["src/app/interfaces/index.ts"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/environment"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
  }
}
```

So in can use path alias in my code, i can import interface from index.ts , like this:

```
import { IProjets, ITaches} from '@interfaces';
```

It build correctly on local dev machine but when i use Bitbucket pipeline , i have many errors:

`````
Error: src/app/menu-principal/home-page/home-page.component.ts:4:70 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@interfaces' or its corresponding type declarations.
2 import { IProjets, ITaches } from '@interfaces';
   ...
Error:                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
        using description file: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/package.json (relative path: ./@interfaces)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/@interfaces doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/@interfaces.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/@interfaces.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/@interfaces.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/@interfaces.js doesn't exist
            as directory
    ````
    I don't know if this is because it don't use same angular/cli on my local dev and image node on bitbucket pipeline or just path alias is not a good idea for my project.
Please help :)
`````

Comment: Remove the paths from tsconfig.app and see if that helps (you might still see an issues with @services though)

Comment: thank you i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a specific file for the path parameter, you can only specify a specific folder path.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

try this :

**tsconfig.json**

```
"paths": {
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/app/interfaces", "src/app/interfaces/*"], 
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/environment"]
    },
```

**in interfaces/index.ts**

```
export * from './IProjets';
export * from'./ITaches';
```

**in component**

```
import {IProjets, ITaches} from "@interfaces/";
```

**Note :** However, it may be inconvenient to keep all of its files in an index.ts file. You may get circular depency error due to interface files that are in nested use.

Comment: Thank you , I try to user paths alis like that